# How can I read PCM linear file in Octave?

Tags: audio, octave

I have a pcm linear file (16 bits) collected with a sampling rate 8000 Hz.

I want to read the file in octave.

Whenever I read it using:

```
x = fread(fid, inf, "short");
sound(x, 8000);
```

I get a very distorted audio.

Comment: In what endianness format is the file data?

Comment: I am closing this question because it's very unclear and too broad. You don't provide the audio file, there is no info about the header and no clear description of what "distorted audio" means. Please refine it, to obtain a good answer.

Comment: Have you checked the range of values of `x`? Maybe the audio data is represented by integer values (-32768...32767) while the `sound()` function assumes them to be (-1...1).

Answer (score 1):

[A. Tanenbaum](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Andrew_S._Tanenbaum) is credited with:

> The nice thing about standards is that you have so many to choose from

Two main options, for PCM or other formats: 1) the reading is not fully adapted 2) the file is not fully compatible.

You can try with other higher-level audio functions like described in [33.1 Audio File Utilities](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.1/Audio-File-Utilities.html#Audio-File-Utilities). And cross-check with hexadecimal editors, or other PCM decoders, that the PCM file is sound. Three quite typical issues are:

- the file is not PCM,
- a problem with the PCM file header,
- a little-endian or big-endian byte-ordering trouble.